# Populating a collection in a list

Tags: c#, linq

I think my LINQ query syntax is wrong.

Here is a brief of what I am trying to do

1. I have a list of People(ICollection of Person) and a list of Addresses(ICollection of Address)
2. A person can have multiple addresses.(so a Person has an an Addresses property of type ICollection)
3. Each Address also has a PersonId to associate it to a Person
4. Assuming I have those two collections but the Person collection has no addresses populated, and ** I want to populate the address collection... why does the Linq below not work?
5. It does not populate the address collection but throws no error
6. Question is, given that I have both collections with data and they have matching types, **is the Linq query syntax below correct**?

   ```
   // people is an ICollection<Person>

   // addressList is an ICollection<Address>

   var query = from person in People
               select new Person
               {
                  Id = person.Id, 
                  Name = person.Name,
                  adresses = (from address in addressList
                              where address.PersonId == person.Id
                              select address).ToList()
               };
   ```

Comment: We can ask that same question to you. Why doesn't it work? Do you receive an error?

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: @CodeCaster thanks for responding. It does not populate. No error is thrown. I have improved my question

Comment: @CommuSoft I didnt get an error. It does not populate at all

Comment: @user919426: Dou you want to create a new list of `Person`? It would be more efficient to store the addresses in the already initialized list of `Person`s...

Comment: @CommuSoft I am more interested in the Linq query syntax. Thats just an example.

Comment: Can only be one thing: `address.PersonId == person.Id` doesn't match for some reason.

Comment: @GertArnold thanks for replying. I suspected that as well and have gone over it over and over again. I will attempt to reproduce it and post the code

Comment: I have updated my question to be clearer on what I am looking for @CodeCaster et al. Asking if there is anything syntactically wrong with my Linq query that might cause the collection property not to be populated

Answer (score 5):

I think your mistake is in your object initializer.You should set the properties like this:

```
select new Person
{
    Id = person.Id, 
    Name = person.Name,
    adresses = (from address in addressList
                where address.PersonId == person.Id
                select address).ToList()
};
```

Comment: Hi @Selman22 Sorry it was my mistake in the example. I have corrected it. You would be right though

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a .GroupJoin to do the job:

```
var result = People.GroupJoin(addressList, p => p.Id, a => a.PersonId, 
                                (p, addresses) => new Person {
                                         Id = p.Id,
                                         name = p.Name,
                                         addresses = addresses });
```